# Cardinal Arithmetic, Examples

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Below you find an excerpt of my notes about cardinal arithmetic. I self-study set theory, so I need someone to check if my notes are correct since I have no teacher and most books leave you alone of how specifically things work. For instance in my book (Deiser, Einführung in die Mengenlehre) the author only gives the result without any explanation.

I just wanted to give me some examples of how this kind of arithmetic works. Can you look if the formalities are correct and if my reasons I give once in a while (usually below the critical formula) are correct too? If not, I‘d appreciate some reasoning about what seems suspicious.

[image]

Comment: All facts here look correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback!